# WP7 PathGeometry error

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, path, pathgeometry

I'm having a strange error with a simple PathGeometry object and I can't seem to figure it out. I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me why this doesn't work.

Here is an example of a working Path, which draws a small triangle:

```
<Path Data="M 8,4 L 12,12 4,12 8,4 Z" Stroke="White" />
```

Here is an example of a Path that does not seem to work for me:

```
<Path Stroke="White">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry Figures="M 8,4 L 12,12 4,12 8,4 Z" />
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

The string in the Data and Figures properties are identical, yet the latter example results in the exception:

> Invalid attribute value M 8,4 L 12,12 4,12 8,4 Z for property Figures.

What I would like to do ultimately is to put the PathGeometry into a ResourceDictionary and reference it as a {StaticResource} so I can re-use my shapes.

**Edit:**

My solution was to instead of trying to reference a PathGeometry with a StaticResource, to instead reference a string resource.

```
<sys:String x:Key="TriangleShape">M 8,4 L 12,12 4,12 8,4 Z</sys:String>
...
<Path Data={StaticResource TriangleShape}" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can tell, path markup syntax, as used by [Path.Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.data%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), isn't supported by PathGeometry.  The [PathGeometry.Figures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathgeometry.figures%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property has to be a collection of PathFigure objects instead.

To specify the above shape in this way, you could do something like the following:

```
    <Path Stroke="White">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="8,4">
                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                            <LineSegment Point="12,12" />
                            <LineSegment Point="4,12" />
                            <LineSegment Point="8,4" />
                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry> 
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this on WP7, only on Silverlight on my PC.

Comment: This indeed works on wp7! It's unfortunately verbose but an acceptable alternative. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Unfortunately referencing a PathGeometry in Path.Data doesn't work either so I think I'm stuck duplicating the Geometry :-/ (e.g. <Path Data="{StaticResource TriangleGeometry}" />)

Comment: Ok now I feel stupid because it works to just make a string resource and bind that instead: <sys:String x:Key="CurrencyGeometry">M 8,4 L 12 12 4 12 8 4 Z</sys:String>  ... ugh.

Comment: Ah well, glad to see you got it sorted.

Comment: @justin.m.chase: could you add your final solution to the question above? I'm sure this would be very useful for others in the future.